# Create a thread using a class constructor as function

Tags: python, multithreading, class, constructor

I know that I can create and start a thread in Python using the following syntax:

```
import threading

tracker_thread = threading.Thread(target=func, args=(x,y,z))
tracker_thread.daemon = True
tracker_thread.start()
```

What I need is to use a class constructor as `target`. I know that a solution for this is the following:

```
def wrap_function(x,y,z):
    MyClas(x,y,z)

tracker_thread = threading.Thread(target=wrap_function, args=(x,y,z))
```

But I am trying to avoid the use of a similar "wrap function", by using only the constructor in the initialization of `Thread`.

How can I do this?

Comment: `threading.Thread(target=MyClass, args=(x, y, z))` didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. The simplest solution is always the best:

```
tracker_thread = threading.Thread(target=MyClass, args=(x,y,z))
```

Thanks to [Sir_FZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3572366/sir-fz) for the comment.

Comment: is it args=[x, y, z] or args=(x, y, z)?

Comment: Yeah -- Python "no special syntax for instantiating objects" wins again! The only time function/class interchange ever got me is in writing a decorator as a class, and use it to decorate a method in Python 3. (hint: you decorator will need a `__get__` method)